# Problem to use cxfreeze to convert script.py to executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I developed a script named `terminal.py` and it runs very good in Python, I am running it on raspberry platform and I am using several external libraries like `AdafruitLCD`, `pad4pi`, `pinput` and others.

I need to execute it with no Python. After I execute  `$cxfreeze terminal.py` and the result is a folder name **dist** with a program `terminal` inside. If I try to execute it like:

> chmod +x terminal
>
> ./terminal

The result is no error, but nothing happens, the LCD 16x2, matricial keyboard, serial port, matricial keyboard 4x4 and everything doesn't work, but if I execute this script `terminal.py` in python IDE it works very well.

I didnt put the script here because it has 650 lines.

Comment: Why do you need to execute it with “no Python”? cx_Freeze packs in a minimal Python distribution – so that's by no means *no Python*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with cx_freeze but I have worked with pyinstaller. Can you try checking with that once if `cx_freeze` is not solving your problem. Using `pyinstaller` is very easy. You can install it using `pip` and bundle a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package with just an easy command like `pyinstaller /path/to/yourscript.py` . You can find more details [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/).

Comment: The pyinstaller worked very well, thank you Solen'ya